# Minecraft Plugin external error

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

Trying to code a Minecraft Plugin and when I run the /fakeop in game I get an external error. The /fakeop (playername) works though

```
public class CortexTroll extends JavaPlugin {

     @Override
     public void onEnable() {}

     @Override
     public void onDisable() {}

     public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
          if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("fakeop")) {
               Player player = (Player) sender;
               Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
               if (args.length == 0) {
                    player.sendMessage("Specify a player to Op. /fakeop <target>");
                    return true;
               }
               player.sendMessage("Fake Opped " + args[0]);
               Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "[" + player.getName() + ": Opped " + args[0] + "]");
               target.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "You are now op!");
          }
          return true;
     }
 }
```

**Error:**

> Illuminatiiiiii issued server command: /fakeop [21:33:10 ERROR]: null
>   org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing
>   command 'fakeop' in plugin CortexTroll v1.0
>           at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46)
>   ~[spigot-1.10.2.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-00359a1]
>           at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141)
>   ~[spigot-1.10.2.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-00359a1]
>           at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:646)
>   ~[spigot-1.10.2.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-00359a1]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1351)
>   [spigot-1.10.2.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-00359a1]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1186)
>   [spigot-1.10.2.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-00359a1]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:45)
>   [spigot-1.10.2.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-00359a1]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:1)
>   [spigot-1.10.2.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-00359a1]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13)
>   [spigot-1.10.2.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-00359a1]
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:45) [spigot-1.10.2.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-00359a1]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:733)
>   [spigot-1.10.2.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-00359a1]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:399)
>   [spigot-1.10.2.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-00359a1]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:672)
>   [spigot-1.10.2.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-00359a1]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:571)
>   [spigot-1.10.2.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-00359a1]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91] Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>           at us.thecortex.cortextroll.CortexTroll.onCommand(CortexTroll.java:29)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44)
>   ~[spigot-1.10.2.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-00359a1]

Comment: *when I run the /fakeop in game I get an external error.* What error? Are you on an external server?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by external server but I added the plugin to my Minecraft server files and in-game when I run the command I get the error. Something in the code is apparently jacked up but IDK what.

Answer (score 3):

Because im not allowed to comment jet, here is what you could try: Move the line below after the if-statement that checks if args.length is 0

```
public Class CortexTroll extends JavaPlugin{

     @Override
     public void onEnable() {}

     @Override
     public void onDisable() {}

     public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
          if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("fakeop")) {
               Player player = (Player) sender;
               if (args.length == 0) {
                    player.sendMessage("Specify a player to Op. /fakeop <target>");
                    return true;
               }
               Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]); // Is now below the if-statement
               player.sendMessage("Fake Opped " + args[0]);
               Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "[" + player.getName() + ": Opped " + args[0] + "]");
               target.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "You are now op!");
          }
          return true;
     }
 }
```

Why should this fix the error?

If you execute `/fakeop` without any argument, args has the length of 0. If you try to access the `args[0]`, you get a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because it wants a Array with length 1.

EDIT: Thanks for pointing out that it isn't a NullPointer.

Comment: Correct fix, except the explanation is incorrect.  Args isn't `null`; its length is 0 (and the error message is about accessing an out-of-range element, not it being null).